# Bean Validation required for enums required?

Tags: java, validation, enums

This might look like a very basic question but I need to clarify.

I have a bean(Mybean) with an enum field.The enum as values ranging from 1-21.

I have to add a JSR 303 validation that that field can't allow values other than 1-21.

Since enum is typesafe,I don't think I need to do this validation at all.

I may need to put this validation whenever I am creating an object of type MyBean.

Please confirm if I am missing anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you put a `@NotNull` constraint on it, it'll have to be one of the enum types.

Comment: Ya,so just a null check will do,rt?

Comment: If you don't want to allow nulls?